# Клиент с JWT авторизацией

Tags: java, spring, jwt

Друзья, подскажите как лучше организовать клиента к сервису с JWT авторизацией. Пишу на spring (использую RestTemplate/WebClient), интересует где и как хранить полученные токены, плюс как безопасно обновлять их в многопоточной среде исполнения. Может есть что-то из коробки? Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Давно делал по данному [гайду](https://youtu.be/yRnSUDx3Y8k), но есть ли там про обновление уже и не помню. Для старта полезный материал в любом случае.

Еще советую почитать данную [тему](https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc). Если кратко, то токены обновления хранить только в куках и с флагами HttpOnly, SameSite, Expires(равен токену обновления) и Path. Токены доступа в гайдах чаще всего хранят в localstorage/sessionstorage, но это неправильно, т.к появляется риск xss-атаки. Единственный вариант - в памяти какого-нибудь сервиса.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.